# Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?

Tags: publications

Using a link as a reference is often problematic as the link might disappear at a future time. However, the content might be of high relevance to the reader, so it might be worthwhile to add it as a reference. Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror"? Publishers don't have the right to just copy and redistribute content without the permission of the original authors.

Comment: @Thomas Maybe like the  Wayback Machine (http://archive.org/about/faqs.php#20)